# Averaging rows by columns with the same name in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the dataset in a CSV file, I want to finds the cells which have the same name in row and column and append them to the list and calculate their average in Python.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily without pandas.

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    matrix = list(reader)

counter = 0
for x in range(1, len(matrix[0])):
    for y in range(1, len(matrix)):
        if matrix[0][x] == matrix[y][0]:
            counter += float(matrix[x][y])

print(counter)
```

Alternatively, reading using pandas and then transforming to numpy:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv").to_numpy()
counter = 0
for x in range(1, len(matrix[0])):
    for y in range(1, len(matrix)):
        if matrix[0][x] == matrix[y][0]:
            counter += float(matrix[x][y])

print(counter)
```